# Unable to add to custom telemetry initializer in Application Insight

Tags: javascript, azure, react-native, azure-application-insights

I am working on a React-Native application and would like to use Application Insights for logging data. For that, I have included the AI JS SDK script statically. The logging is working as expected and I am able to log traces and exceptions. However, I have a requirement where for each log (trace, exception or events), some specific custom properties need to be added.

To achieve this I am trying to add a custom telemetry initializer (I am following this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md)). The problem is that I am getting an error saying that `AppInsights.queue.push` is undefined. Here is my full code:

```
import Microsoft from "./ai.0";
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  AppInsights = null;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var snippet = {
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    };
    var init = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Initialization(snippet);
    this.AppInsights = init.loadAppInsights();
    this.AppInsights.trackPageView("First Page", null, {Comp: "App"},{hit:"1"}, 100); //This step is working

    this.AppInsights.queue.push(function() { //This is where it breaks;
      this.AppInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function(envelope) {
        var telemetryItem = envelope.data.baseData;

        telemetryItem.Properties = telemetryItem.Properties || {};
        telemetryItem.Properties["MyCustomProperty_1"] = "This is a custom property";
        telemetryItem.Properties["MyCustomProperty_2"] = "This is another custom property";
      });
    });
  }
```

What am I missing here?

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old, but there's no need to access the queue or context directly. You can just call `addTelemetryInitializer` directly off of the `AppInsightsInitializer` instance:

```
init.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
        var telemetryItem = envelope.data.baseData;

        telemetryItem.Properties = telemetryItem.Properties || {};
        telemetryItem.Properties["MyCustomProperty_1"] = "This is a custom property";
        telemetryItem.Properties["MyCustomProperty_2"] = "This is another custom property";
      });
```

Also make sure the filters are added after AppInsights is initialized (by calling `loadAppInsights`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the  fact it happens when the code snippet is invoked twice, and in the second time there is no "queue" anymore. The solution is to wrap the code snippet with a check

```
if (this.AppInsights.queue) {
        this.AppInsights.queue.push(function() { //This is where it breaks;
        this.AppInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function(envelope) {
        var telemetryItem = envelope.data.baseData;

        telemetryItem.Properties = telemetryItem.Properties || {};
        telemetryItem.Properties["MyCustomProperty_1"] = "This is a custom property";
        telemetryItem.Properties["MyCustomProperty_2"] = "This is another custom property";
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Let me try that, but I was able to have a workaround by directly adding the telemetry initializer (i.e. didn't push it in the queue), just wrote this.AppInsights.context.add( ... ) and remove this.AppInsights.queue.push method.

Comment: Nope didn't work. The error is gone but no custom property went in.

Comment: in the above try to initialize and see this.AppInsights.queue = [];

Comment: did you try it out?

Comment: It took out the error but the data didn't go through.